# Accessing chart properties (like chart title) via epplus in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, epplus

I am trying to get title of an existing chart that is already present in my excel worksheet. i don't have ms office installed on server. So i am using EPPlus library. I am able to add new chart in worksheet but i want to retrieve chart title of an existing chart . Is there any way i can get it via epplus ?

i have tried the following the code :

```
                    string file = @"c:\test.xlsm";
                    FileInfo exlName = new FileInfo(file);
                    using (ExcelPackage package = new ExcelPackage(exlName))
                    {
                        var logSheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Name == "DEMO CHARTS");  //this worksheet contains chart in it 
                        if (logSheet != null)
                        {
                            var chart = logSheet.Drawings["Chart 1"] as ExcelChart;
                            var title = chart.Title;
                        }
                    }
```

Comment: What code have you tired (might want to post it).  See if this helps at all: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42393711/how-to-display-percentages-with-decimals-in-an-epplus-pie-chart/42458605#42458605

Comment: @Ernie , i have tried using the above code and getting error as the given key was not found in dictionary

Comment: Did you confirm that chart exists in the collection/Excel file?  If you inspect `Drawings` do you see anything in it?

Comment: No , Drawings gives a `KeyNotFoundException` . So my question is how to relate the chart present in excel worksheet in code using epplus ?

Answer (score 0):

enumerate through the drawings collection on your worksheet - make sure the object is an excelchart (not a picture for example) - then query the innerText (or innerXml) to find your title.

```
            foreach(var drawing in worksheet.Drawings)
            {
                if (drawing is ExcelChart)
                {
                    if (((ExcelChart)drawing).ChartXml.InnerText.Contains("YOUR GRAPH TITLE"))
                    {
            //-- convert and use here...
            var chart = drawing as ExcelBarChart;
                    }
                }
            }
```

Note: The answer below isn't perfect, as if your chart title is in the innertext for the drawing object (e.g. your chart title is "!") - it won't work, and in that case you will need to use the InnerXML property instead and search it using XDom..