# EPPlus Pie Chart conditional data labels

Tags: c#, epplus

C#, Using Eppplus, creating a Piechart with over 100 "slices", only want to show datalabels/Category Name whose percent of the pie is over (for example) 5%.  Suggestions?

...
...fill chart data - 100 lines in columns 1 and 2 where column 1 is the category, column 2 is a number

```
chart = (ExcelPieChart)ws1.Drawings.AddChart("TestChart, eChartType.Pie);
chart.Title.Text = "Chart Title";
var serie = chart.Series.Add(ExcelRange.GetAddress(2, 2, 101,2 ), 
   ExcelRange.GetAddress(2, 1, 101, 1 ));

chart.DataLabel.ShowPercent = false;
chart.SetSize(900, 400);
chart.SetPosition(50, 250);

chart.Legend.Remove();
chart.DataLabel.ShowCategory = true;
chart.DataLabel.ShowLeaderLines = true;
```

shows ALL data labels regardless of size  only want those that are 5% of total or more.  Suggestions?

Comment: What exactly are you asking. We're no code writing service. Please read the [ask] section of our [help]. If you run into specific issues solving your problem, feel free to ask them here.

Comment: Edited to show some code for clarification

Comment: Is that something that Excel proper can even do?  If not, you may have to do something with the raw XML generated by EPPlus but that is a very difficult option as you would have to know exactly how much data is going to be in the pie chart and prepopluate what excel is going to generate.  Here is a somewhat similar concept: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42393711/how-to-display-percentages-with-decimals-in-an-epplus-pie-chart